# Saivng copy of dom before javascript rendering

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do as following:

BEFORE OTHER JAVASCRIPT RENDERING (handlebars etc)

1. Add unique identifier to each element
2. load DOM with unique identifiers in variable.
3. Do all other javascript rendering

NOW I HAVE COPY OF INITIAL HTML JUST WITH UNIQUE IDENTIFIERS

4. make some changes to html live
5. changes apply to saved document in variable
6. remove identifiers
   7  push on server

Is this good approach for live changing html and is it possible?

Comment: I don't get your question. Please be more specific

Comment: I am making logic for front end editing html, but there are problems, how i can know which element is pair with that element on server file because there are javascript renderings that changes html and there is server side minification, so my aproach is to somehow identify each element and map it  to original html file, but now i am aproaching different, in my development mode i will attach unique ids on every element ON SERVER, and html with identifiers will be already there on client so i can modify it.